# SQL Server show non matching records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have table like below .

```
create table #test (NAME varchar(100),TAGint,checkVAL varchar(1),CATEGORY int)

insert into #test values('jkl',1,'y',100)
insert into #test values('abc',1,'y',100)
insert into #test values('abc',1,'y',101)
insert into #test values('abc',2,'n',102)
insert into #test values('abc',3,'n',103)
insert into #test values('xyz',2,'y',104)
insert into #test values('xyz',1,'y',105)

insert into #test values('pqr',1,'y',105)
insert into #test values('pqr',1,'y',106)
insert into #test values('pqr',1,'y',106)
```

Now I want to show those records which have diffrent values in columns **name , tag , checkVal .**
This is what I have done.

```
select * from #test

;with cte as
(
select *,row_number() over(partition by NAME,TAG,checkVAL order by CATEGORY ) as rownum
from #test
)

select * from cte
where rownum=1
```

This is what is being returned

```
NAME    TAG  checkVAL  CATEGORY rownum
-----------------------------------------
abc     1      y       100      1
abc     2      n       102      1
abc     3      n       103      1
jkl     1      y       100      1  --> This row should not come
pqr     1      y       105      1  --> This row should not come
xyz     1      y       105      1
xyz     2      y       104      1
```

What I am trying is that for any value in column NAME , if values are different in TAG or checkVAL or both , then those rows should only be shown.

Below row

```
jkl     1      y       100      1
```

Should not be shown because `jkl` has no other row to match.

Below row should not be shown

```
   pqr      1      y       105      1
```

because all rows with **NAME** column value as `pqr` have same values in **TAG** and **checkVAL** columns

I want to preferably approach using CTE  .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this -

```
select 
* 
from #test a
where exists
(
    select * 
    from 
    #test b
    where a.name = b.name and (a.tag <> b.tag or a.checkVAL <> b.checkVAL)
)
```

Comment: can this be done by CTE , I have to plug in the solution into further complex procedure